# How to access MediaStore from broadcast receiver when app is closed in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I am creating a testing app that lets users create custom notifications to be displayed sometime in the future. I am using `AlarmManager` to schedule the notifications passing it a `PendingIntent` like this:

```
         long afterFiveMinutes = getTime(notificationTime.FIVE_MINUTES);
                Intent fiveMinuteIntent = new Intent(application, NotificationReceiver.class);
                fiveMinuteIntent.putExtra("TITLE",notificationTitle);
                fiveMinuteIntent.putExtra("CONTENT", notificationContent);
                fiveMinuteIntent.putExtra("IMAGE", imageUriMutableLiveData.getValue().toString());
                PendingIntent fivePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(application,101,fiveMinuteIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,afterFiveMinutes,fivePendingIntent);
```

And then in my `NotificationReceiver` I call `showNotification()` from the `onReceive()` method, this method looks like this:

```
  private void showNotification(String title, String content, Uri image, Context context){

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"s");
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(content);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);

        if(image != null) {
            try{
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),image);
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(bitmap)
                .bigLargeIcon(null));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TEST", "Image is null for some reason");
        }

        notificationManager.notify(3,notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

The problem is this: When I have my app opened in the foreground or background, after 5 minutes I receive the notification with the image I have selected, but when I close the app I still receive the notification after 5 minutes, but no image is displayed. How can I access the `MediaStore` even when the app is closed?

Comment: It is unclear if you cannot display an image or not access the mediastore.

Comment: You're right, it is unclear to me as well,  my guessing is that I cannot access the mediastore when the app is closed, since I am able to display the image when I have the app open in the background.

Comment: That is no answer. It should be easy for you to find out what happens if you use some log statements

Comment: Thank you for your message! I edited my code to show the log statement I am trying to use to catch if the image is null when the app is closed, but I don't receive any logs if the app is closed, do you have any other suggestions on things I could try @blackapps ?

Comment: I see only one log statement in your code so what do you expect?

Comment: `but no image is displayed. ` Please be exact. Does getBitmap() return null? Do you have an Exception there?

Comment: How did you obtain that image uri? And when? How does it look like?